# Non-inverting operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need some help with a non-inverting operational amplifier, particulary the [AD8041A](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8041.pdf).

I want a 3.3 V input to generate 11.5 V output. With this circuit, it seems to work OK:

[image]

V2 DC sweep:

[image]

But when I increase resistance, the output goes to mV levels:

[image]

[image]

What's happening here?

Comment: AD8041 is not an op amp.

Comment: What's that "A" symbol above R1 in the second version.

Comment: A is opamp output node. i think the spice model is broken.

Comment: What did you do with the "enable" input? "Same" as AD8021 ... (24 V)

Comment: AD8041 seems to be an op-amp for video uses, it can be also used in an analog  "multiplexer" or a switched amplifier with a synchro pulse disabling function...

Comment: What are the frequencies of interest in the input signal? *I want a 3.3 V input to generate 11.5 V output* There are infinitely many such circuits. You've given the intercept of the response function - what's the slope (gain) you need? How did you arrive at this part number? What do you actually want/need to do? If you seem to need high bandwidth, then large resistors are the last thing you'd be using in the feedback loop...

Answer (score 3):

This device is a high speed (160 MHz) op-amp which also has an active low disable input, which you have not shown. But it should work if this pin is left floating. The absolute maximum supply voltage is 12.5 VDC, so your 12V is dangerously close to the limit. I question why you need such a high speed device if all you want to do is drive 3.3V to get 11.5V into a 10k load. The input resistance is 160k, which could affect performance with higher resistance feedback resistors, although 5k and 2k should still work.

Perhaps you might explain why you have chosen this device for your application. It is certainly not appropriate for a simple non-inverting DC amplifier. And such a high speed device may need special care for PCB layout and bypass capacitors, which are also not shown on your schematic. Are you getting this behavior only with your simulator, or do you have an actual circuit?

Here is a simulation using LTSpice:

[image: NI Amp AD8041]

Answer (score 0):

As James pointed out in the comments, the "A" node symbol looks suspicious. It looks like the net is being severed.

Running the simulation in LTspice, the AD8041**A** model supplied in LTspice is broken (brings up an error message). The AD8041 model appears to work.

You have a couple issues with your circuit which makes it a marginal design.

- The maximum specified power supply voltage is 12.6V. Your power supply is very close to maximum. Recommended is 3 V to 10V.
- The output is very close to the power supply rail. Depending on the load, the part may not operate as you want - depending on the output load.

You may want to consider using an opamp that can handle a larger power supply voltage and raising the 12 V supply to something like 15V.

The simulation below shows the part operating with various load resistances. V(in) = 3.3 V, the output is sensitive to the load resistance.
You must consider the impact of the feedback resistors as they are in parallel with the load.

[image]

Comment: I can't find any documentation for AD8041A, although it appears several places in the AD8041 data sheet. And the full part numbers include the "A" suffix.

Comment: The parameters for "AD8041" are for "AD8041A". "A" is a suffix for "Analog Devices", "industrial" device for use -40° -> 85 °C ? Or "A" generic to "SMD"?

Comment: ? Question to AD https://ez.analog.com/amplifiers/f/q-a/14899/ad8041arz-top-marking

Answer (score 0):

thanks, guys! as mentioned earlier, my spice model for AD8041A seems broken. Anyway, I did an update and will be going with this:

[image]

This should work. Spice simulation looks OK.